# stream contents of 1GB file to sqlite table under single column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jooq, clob

Below implementation gives Out of Memory Error for files of 1 GB size with 4 GB heap space. Files.lines will return a stream but while running Collectors.joining it gives Heap Error.

Can we stream a file with lesser memory footprint using jooq and jdbc preserving original line separators ?

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);

dsl.createTable(TABLE1)
            .column(COL1, SQLDataType.CLOB)
            .column(COL2, SQLDataType.CLOB)
            .execute();

dsl.insertInto(TABLE1)
                .columns(COL1, COL2)
                .values(VAL1, lines
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())))
                .execute();
```

Error ->

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:76) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:484) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.StringJoiner.add(StringJoiner.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.stream.Collectors$$Lambda$491/1699129225.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ's default data type binding for `CLOB` data type treats the `CLOB` type as an ordinary `String`, which works well for small to mid sized lobs. For larger lobs, the streaming version of the JDBC API would be more suitable. Ideally, you would create your own data type binding, where you optimise your write operation for streaming:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

For example:

```java
class StreamingLobBinding implements Binding<String, File> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<File> ctx) {
        // Ideally: register the input stream somewhere for explicit resource management
        ctx.statement()
           .setBinaryStream(ctx.index(), new FileInputStream(ctx.value()));
    }
}
```

And then, you can either apply this binding to your column and have the code generator pick it up as documented in the above link, or you apply it only for single usage:

```java
DataType<File> fileType = COL2.getDataType().asConvertedDataType(new StreamingLobBinding());
Field<File> fileCol = DSL.field(COL2.getName(), fileType);
dsl.insertInto(TABLE1)
   .columns(COL1, fileCol)
   .values(VAL1, DSL.val(theFile, fileType))
   .execute();
```

Note that currently, you may need to register your input stream in some `ThreadLocal` to remember it and clean it up after statement execution. A future jOOQ version will offer SPI for handling that: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7591

Answer (score 2):

Since `sqlite-jdbc` throws `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` using `setBinaryStream`, there is one more approach as suggested in github issue above.

```
dsl.insertInto(TABLE1)
        .columns(TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2)
        .values("ABB", null)
        .execute();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
int bytesCount = 0;
String line = null;
int value = 0;
Field<String> coalesce = DSL.coalesce(TABLE1.COL2, "");
char[] buffer = new char[100 * 1000 * 1000];

while ((value = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    lines.append(String.valueOf(buffer, 0, value));
    bytesCount += lines.length();
    if (bytesCount >= 100 * 1000 * 1000) {

        dsl.update(TABLE1).set(TABLE1.COL2, DSL.concat(coalesce, lines.toString())).where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB")).execute();
        bytesCount = 0;
        lines.setLength(0);
    }
}

if (lines.length() > 0) {
   dsl.update(TABLE1).set(TABLE1.COL2, DSL.concat(coalesce, lines.toString())).where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB")).execute();
}
reader.close();
```